# Extract Xdocument soap response body into new Xdocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have XML which is parsed into an XDocument:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <MyResponse xmlns="https://www.domain.net/">
      <Node1>0</Node1>
    </MyResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Basically I am trying to create a new XDocument which has its root as

```
<MyResponse xmlns="https://www.domain.net/">
      <Node1>0</Node1>
    </MyResponse>
```

So in essence I am trying to extract this from the soap body.  I have tried parsing this using Linq but cannot seem to return a new XDocument with this new root.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `new XDocument( old.Element( "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope" ).Element( "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body" ).Element( "{https://www.domain.net/}MyResponse" ) )`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace SO39545160
{
  class Program
  {
    static string xmlSource = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" +
      "<soap:Body>" +
      "<MyResponse xmlns = \"https://www.domain.net/\" >" +
      "<Node1 > 0 </Node1 >" +
      "</MyResponse>" +
      "</soap:Body>" +
      "</soap:Envelope>";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlSource);
      var subXml = xdoc.Document.Elements(XName.Get(@"{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope")).Elements(XName.Get(@"{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body")).Elements(XName.Get(@"{https://www.domain.net/}MyResponse"));

      foreach (var node in subXml)
      {
        XDocument myRespDoc = new XDocument(node);
        Console.WriteLine(myRespDoc);
      }
      Console.WriteLine();

      Console.WriteLine("END");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: returns zero results;

Comment: @CR41G14: When I run it it prints out the <MyResponse...> to the console in the foreach-loop. Maybe the xmlSource string was corrupted when you copied it?

Comment: This worked  var newDoc = XDocument(response.Document.Descendants(XName.Get("MyResponse", "https://www.domain.net/"))); Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: @CR41G14: It's a little unfair to downvote my answer though ;-)

Comment: can't reverse yet.